# Install pandas for Python 2.6

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.6

Currently I have two versions of python (2.6 and 2.7) on my unix machine.

Python 2.7 has already got pandas installed for it but 2.6 doesn't have.
So, I'm trying to install pandas specifically for python2.6 as my production environment has got ONLY python 2.6 and I cannot upgrade that at this point of time.
When I tried installing it using the below command, it says "Requirement already satisfied" pointing to python2.7 and nothing got added to python 2.6.

```
@user  pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in 
            /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.0 in 
            /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in 
            /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in 
            /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil-
            >pandas)
```

Please advice on how do I specifically install Pandas for Python2.6.

Comment: how do call the python2.6 binary? `python2.6`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you are asking. I'm pretty new to Python.

Comment: `pip` doesn't come with Python 2.6, so how did you install it?

Comment: [user24@user25 ]$ cd /usr/lib64/python2.6 
    [user24@user25 python2.6]$ pip
    pip     pip2    pip2.7

Comment: Above listed the pip commands. so I ran it. I don't know if its picking from Python 2.7

Comment: what doess `which pip2` give you?

Comment: Sorry, do I have to install pip first for 2.6 and then try again?

Comment: I did a `tab key stroke` after typing `pip` getting into the 2.6 folder and that listed all pip's - **pip,pip2,pip2.7**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed Python 2.6 in the usual directory, you can just run

```
C:\Python26\Scripts\pip.exe
```

or go to that directory in a Command Prompt and run

```
.\pip.exe
```

Oops. Just noticed you're on a UNIX box.  But the result is the same. You must specify the full path to the pip you want, or go to the directory and run `.\pip`

The other pip and python are in the system "path", the list of places that get searched for an executable. So, you have to tell the O/S exactly which `pip` you want to run. Otherwise, if you just say `pip`, it will find whichever one it can find in the system path.

Comment: Or `python2.6 -m pip`, assuming that's the command on the PATH

Comment: Did you mean this folder - "/usr/lib64/python2.6" on unix

Comment: Probably not, but I'm on a Mac, so I don't have access to Linux. But if you do a `which python` or `where python` or `whereis python`, one of them  should show you where the Py2.7 executable is. Py 2.6 should be in a comparable directory.  The same goes for pip.